# Symfony 1.4 admin generator how I can show i18n fields in View

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I used admin generator, there are tables that have i18n fields,I have the problem that in view/show not print the fields with i18n, but hen I'm editing show i18n correct, but in show/view not draw these fields.

How I can configure to show i18n fields in view?

The schema is:

```
Coleccio:
  actAs: 
    I18n:
      fields: [descripcio]
  columns:
    nom:        { type: string(50), notnull: true, unique: true }
    descripcio:   { type: text, notnull: true }
    is_historic:  { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 0 }

Article:
  columns:
    coleccio_id:        { type: integer, notnull: true }
    nom_foto: {  type: string(50), notnull: true}
    foto:   { type: string(255), notnull: true }    
  relations:
    Coleccio: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: coleccio_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Article_FK }

Provincia:
  columns:
    nom: { type: string(50), notnull: true, unique: true }

Punts_Venda:
  columns:
    provincia_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    nom:   { type: string(50), notnull: true }
    direccio:   { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    ciutat:   { type: string(50), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Provincia: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: provincia_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Punts_Venda_FK }

Primera_Persona:
  actAs:    
    I18n:
      fields: [nom, descripcio]      
  columns:
    name: { type: string(80), notnull: true }
    nom: { type: string(80), notnull: true }
    descripcio:   { type: text, notnull: true }


Imatges_Primera_Persona:
  columns:
    primera_persona_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    nom: { type: string(50), notnull: true }
    foto:   { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    codi:   { type: string(100), notnull: false}
  relations:
    Primera_Persona: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: primera_persona_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Imatges_Primera_Persona_FK }

Elements_Singulars:
  actAs:    
    I18n:
      fields: [nom, descripcio]
  columns:
    name: { type: string(80), notnull: true }
    nom: { type: string(80), notnull: true }
    descripcio:   { type: text, notnull: true }
    foto:   { type: string(255), notnull: true }
```

Thanks Regards

Comment: Can you show your controler, view and model?

Answer (score 0):

Clean symfony cache (symfony cc), clean your browser cache, and in settings.yml for your app, try this:

```
i18n:                   on
```